# How To Store Mixed Array Data?

Tags: c#, arrays, types

Let's say I have an array I need to store string values as well as double values.  I know I can store the doubles as strings, and just deal with the conversions, but is it possible to use an array with two data types?

Comment: How much performance is important? If it is, I could have tried writing a custom class storing them separately but exposing them as one.

Comment: how do you detect whether it's a double or string you pull out. Are they always in the same order or?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use `object[]` and do some type checking. You will get some boxing/unboxing when accessing the doubles, but that will be faster than `double.Parse()` anyway.

An alternative is to create a class with both types and a marker:

```
class StringOrDouble
{
    private double d;
    private string s;
    private bool isString;

    StringOrDouble(double d)
    {
        this.d = d;
        isString = false;
    }

    StringOrDouble(string s)
    {
        this.s = s;
        isString = true;
    }

    double D
    {
        get
        {
            if (isString)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("this is a string");
            return d;
        }
    }

    string S
    {
        get
        {
            if (!isString)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("this is a double");
            return s;
        }
    }
    bool IsString { get { return isString; } }
}
```

and then create an array of StringOrDouble. This will save you from some typechecking and boxing, but will have a larger memory overhead.

Comment: ^ is what you are describing here a structure?

Answer (score 5):

sure use:

```
object[], ArrayList, or List<Object>;
```

You'll have to cast, and probably pay a boxing penalty for the doubles, but they will allow you to store two different types.

Comment: Which would you recommend for maximum efficiency? I'm dealing with 50k element sized arays.

Comment: @Soo - Is it always 50k elements and is each of the 50k elements always filled?

Comment: I would think, that if you are needing to resize the array, that the arraylist or List<Object> would be better. If there is no resizing necessary, then just use an object[], as that will be better for fast lookup than the List<Object> or ArrayList.

Comment: 50k...The three pretty much do the same thing, in terms of storage, but honestly, I would probably reconsider using an array at all and try and use several smaller structures.

Comment: Array is generally fastest, since it doesn't have the variable-length overhead of ArrayList and List.

Answer (score 5):

Not the most efficient usage, but how about for flexibility:

```
var a = new object[] {1,2,3,"paul",5.5}
```

or even

```
var a = new object[] {1,2,3,"paul",5.5, new List<string>() {"apple","banana","pear"}  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`object[]` and `ArrayList` are two decent options; it depends on whether you need a traditional fixed-length array or a vector (variable-length array). Further, I would "wrap" one of these in a custom class that did some type-checking, if strings and doubles are the ONLY things you can deal with, and you need to be able to get them back out as strings and doubles.